# Determining IE8's Document Mode diagram is wrong, or am I missing something?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, user-agent, ie8-compatibility-mode

I'm kind of lost with how IE8 determines the document mode. I got contradictions.

### Setup

This is what a generated web page header looks like on my website, please note the doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head">
    <meta id="IE8" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
    ...
```

I'm using the **meta http-equiv** setted to **X-UA-Compatible** to force it to render in "standard mode", because this website has been made so. The website is on another machine in the company LAN (**10.1.x.x**).

Everything is ok up to now, but I'm having difficulties with the compatibility settings window:

### Results:

When nothing is checked and listed in compatibility settings, user agent is:

> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E) [**ok**]

When only "Display all websites in Compatibility View" is checked:

> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E) [**coherent but not expected**]

When only "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View" is checked:

> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E) [**not ok**]

When the URL is added to the list of "Websites you've added to Compatibility View":

> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E) [**coherent but not expected**]

According to the following [IE blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/03/02/how-ie8-determines-document-mode.aspx) diagram, if the meta tag X-UA-Compatible is **present** and value is **IE=8**, the renderer is setted to "**Standards mode**".
As just described, that is not the case. Meta was always IE=8 but the user agent changed.
The diagram takes care of the compatibility view settings after the X-UA-Compatible meta check. In my case, it looks like the opposite.
Is the diagram wrong?

### Questions:

- Why the user agent is msie 8.0 when "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View" is checked?! (is it because of my meta? Is http://10.1.x.x/ really considered as an intranet website?)
- Why the user agent is msie 7.0 when "Display all websites in Compatibility View" is checked??? (this override my meta ? but not according to diagram)
- Why the user agent is msie 7.0 when the site is added to the compatibility list ?

According to the diagram, my doctype falls in the "**Almost Standards Mode**" category.
Seems there's a better meta to force IE8 standard mode, but according to the doctype:

```
<meta id="IE8" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="**IE=EmulateIE8**" />
```

Is it better to use it, or the one I'm currently using (force IE=8)?
Seems Almost Standards Mode is exactly the Standard Mode with a subtle change for the rendering of images in a table, ok but... which one should I pick?

Then again the diagram mention "IE=Emulate8" but [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/08/27/introducing-compatibility-view.aspx) talks about "IE=EmulateIE8", seems like the later is the correct version [according to the documentation of http-equiv](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533876%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Is there a way to detect (client side/network) if IE is in "Almost Standards Mode" or "Standards Mode" ?

A few links worth mentioning:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/08/27/introducing-compatibility-view.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/02/16/just-the-facts-recap-of-compatibility-view.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533876(VS.85).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/cc288325(VS.85).aspx

http://blog.strictly-software.com/2009/03/detecting-ie-8-compatibility-modes-with.html

http://phrogz.net/ie8-intranet-compatibility-view

http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/ -> http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/ie8-mode.png

```
javascript:alert(navigator.userAgent)
javascript:alert(document.compatMode);
javascript:alert(document.documentMode);
```

Answer (score -1):

IE Dev tools indicate which rendering engine is being used.

[image: IE Dev tools]

Don't rely on the User Agent string to determine the rendering engine.